# Unity: Dimensions of color surface does not match dimensions of depth surface

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rendering, render-to-texture

I am receiving the error, "Dimensions of color surface does not match dimensions of depth surface" whenever I attempt to use my screenshot code, without any callstack or anything further insight of what I am doing wrong.

I have a separate camera from my main camera, whose purpose is to take screenshots at different angles.  Hierarchy as such:

[image: Hierarchy]

- The main camera captures the 3D scene just like a normal main camera would, including post-processing components.  No HDR or MSAA.
  [image: Post-processing components]
- The GUI camera captures just the UI layer.  Nothing enabled except MSAA.
- The canvas and image are simply a watermark, rendered by the GUI camera.

I point both the main camera and GUI camera to the same target render texture.  When ready to take a screenshot, I enable the camera components, thus Unity takes over and tells them to render the frame.  In the `OnRenderImage` callback, I disable the camera so it can be used again, I remove the render texture I previously assigned, extract the pixels, and save it as a PNG.

In a separate test, this all seems to work as intended.  No error messages.  However, when playing the full game, suddenly I receive the dimensions errors upon each screenshot.

I have read that `RenderTexture.IsCreated` will test if the render texture is still available.  Supposedly, it will be set to false due to a large variety of events, such as window changes.  I have made it impossible to even get the reference to the render texture without it checking if the `IsCreated` bool is true.  I have also tested if the render texture matches its `Descriptor` property, out of paranoia.  All of these checks succeed.

I don't know what to look at next.

What is SUPER strange is I have a GIF generator, using quite similar code, that's much more complicated, and it does not suffer from this problem.

Has anyone dealt with this error before?  Any hints at all?

Comment: You might be better off with these questions at - https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ - or - https://gamedev.net/ - Or on one of the Discord Channels for game development / graphics programming of which there are several.